# How to search regexp in Nokogiri document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying a search mail address in Nokogiri document in this way

```
  def search_mail(link)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link)).to_s
    mail = doc.scan(/[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i)
  end
```

but this method is too long, is it possible to do the same thing only without converting the document into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your input is HTML, chances are good that the email will be inside a  tag, probably with a "mailto", so we could do:

```
tags = []
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
doc.xpath("//a/@href[starts-with(.,'mailto')]").each do |elem|
  tags << elem.value
end

p tags
```

This would output all the emails found into a elements using 'mailto'.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but not always an email note `mailto`